# Automatic refresh <li> order by their id in a jquery sortable #div

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I need that, when a #sortable receive an item, it automatic refreshes its own `<li>`'s order, ordering `<li>`s alphabeticly by their **id** attribute.

```
<head><script>
    $( "#titolari, #panchina" ).sortable({
           receive: function(event, ui) {
                refresh order of <li> alphabeticly by their id,
           }
    });
</script></head>
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)  SO is not a [_we code things for you_ site](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: I'm rookie. If you could only give me a clue fo that function, I'll try. I don't have any idea how to handle this...

Answer (score 0):

Firstly; that function you want a clue about.. it doesn't exactly matter.. or rather, the parameters do not, unless you want to do something with the ui or event data.  Receive executes whenever an element is received from another, [linked](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#option-connectWith) list.  JS has an in-built [sort function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), and that combined with jquery, and the UI bit, will allow for this to work.

The way to combine it all..  get the element array of li elements using jquery (`$('element')` returns an array), sort that array using an anonymous function that compares the id values of the `a` and `b` variables(of the anonymous function), and execute the sort based on when(and where) the receive event occurs.  I have a working example, but I'd rather like to see you try something before I post it here.  I've explained how to achieve the desired result to the best of my ability without giving away everything.